# Spring Boot: Cannot change version of project facet to 3.1

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, web-applications

I am working on a Spring Boot web application and facing some problem with Project Facets. By default, the java compiler version is 1.6 and project facet is 2.3 but am working on Java 8. When I try to change jre library to 1.8 in java build path and try changing Dynamic Web Module to 3.1, i get this error:

```
Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 3.1.   MyApplication       line 1  Maven Java EE Configuration Problem
```

This problem is occuring after I did JSP configuration in Spring Boot application and removed web.xml which was of no use. The content of my `application.properties` is:

```
#JSP Settings
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this..

vim /.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml

change jst.web property to 3.1

i refer from here..
https://www.admfactory.com/how-to-fix-cannot-change-version-of-project-facet-dynamic-web-module-to-3-1-error-in-eclipse/